# Selectors- How do I select the first input in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to get to the first input in the a div (class=form-group) to make the first input required.

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
       <div class="form-text-field first-name">
           <input type="text" id="firstName1" class="signup-input firstName" name="first[1]" placeholder="">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
       <div class="form-text-field last-name">
           <input type="text" id="lastName1" class="signup-input lastName" name="last[1]" placeholder="optional">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="form-text-field email">
           <input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value email" name="email[1]"  placeholder="e.g. example@url.com"/>
           <span class="common-sprite disNone sign-up-cross first clone"></span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I select the first input (firstName) on click the third element (email)?

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: _"How can I select the first input (firstName) on click the third element (email)?"_ When you click the third element (email), what do you want to do with the first input?

Comment: "on click the third element (email)" .. you have `.email` on `div` and `input`.. which element are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to narrow the selector down further for performance reasons you could use the following:

```
$('div.form-group > div:first > div > input:first')
```

This would become:

```js
$(function() {
   $('#inputMail1 ').click(function(){
       $('div.form-group > div:first > div > input:first').focus();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group clearfix">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
       <div class="form-text-field first-name">
           <input type="text" id="firstName1" class="signup-input firstName" name="first[1]" placeholder="">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
       <div class="form-text-field last-name">
           <input type="text" id="lastName1" class="signup-input lastName" name="last[1]" placeholder="optional">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="form-text-field email">
           <input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value email" name="email[1]"  placeholder="e.g. example@url.com"/>
           <span class="common-sprite disNone sign-up-cross first clone"></span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It s wrong, he want select firstName of this clearfix not first in page

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Really, I thought it was correct.

Comment: @hutchonoid, `$('div.form-group > div:first > div:first > input:first')`  ??

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Running the code works though with the mark-up given. I see what you mean though.

Comment: @saritrotshild Can you update the question with the other structure you have? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @hutchonoid- I have multi divs.....each div is displayed in a line with the 3 inputs.

Comment: this answer, like many of the others that use `.eq` and `parentNode`.. is  dependent on the current structure of the markup (html) in your example.. if you were to add another `div` before the `div` that wraps your firstName `input`.. this solution, and many of the other, would break..

Comment: @BrettCaswell True, I know what you mean good point. I was just going from current markup.

Comment: so why use `"div > div > div > input:first"` formats?.. because in css style declarations (which probably isn't relevant to jQuery's CssSelector-like syntax), this format of the selector takes priority over `input:first` because it starts at a node closer to `body`.

Answer (score 1):

see code snippet.

[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) = search for first maching parent.

[siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) = search for sibling element.

[first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) = get the first matching element.

[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) = get the first matching child element.

[val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) = get the value of the input element.

```js
(function($) {

  $('body').on('click', '.email', function() {

    var firstname = $(this).closest('.col-md-4').siblings().first().find('.firstName').val();

    alert(firstname);

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="form-text-field first-name">
      <input type="text" id="firstName1" class="signup-input firstName" name="first[1]" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-text-field last-name">
      <input type="text" id="lastName1" class="signup-input lastName" name="last[1]" placeholder="optional">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-text-field email">
      <input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value email" name="email[1]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com" />
      <span class="common-sprite disNone sign-up-cross first clone"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

greetings timotheus

Comment: I like that you're giving references to the jQuery methods.. but I would still prefer solutions with CssSelectors.. that is.. as 'better' (upvoted) answers.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery

```
$('#inputMail1').click(function(){
$( "input" ).first().focus();
});
```

Comment: Use id="firstName1" ? Not sure no input berfore this code and incomplete answer no trigger of click

Comment: $('#inputMail1').click(function(){
$( "input" ).first().focus();
});

Comment: I have multi divs like the one above.... how it should know to select the first input in the relevant div?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I select the first input (firstName) on click the third element (email)?

If you want to get the first `input` element when clicking on the third `.form-text-field` element:

```
$('.form-group .form-text-field').eq(2).on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.form-text-field:first input:first');
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2b4j0027/)

---

Or you could select the element by `id` rather than `.eq(2)`:

```
$('#inputMail1').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.form-text-field:first input:first');
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/am6p563o/)

Answer (score 0):

You cna use it

```
$('.signup-input.email').on('click',function(){<-trigger on click

   $(this).closest('.clearfix').find('.firstName'); <- get firstname of this clearfix

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('inputMail1').parentNode.parentNode.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('firstName1').focus();
};
```

Somethink like this?

Comment: note: this doesn't use or require jQuery library.. (also, I would use `addEventListener`).. and `querySelector`

Comment: If there is only one handler, it's not necessary to use addEventListener/attachEvent, but if there are more than one handlers, you are absolutely right!

Comment: you don't know if there is ever just 1 handler.. the user-agent might use extensions that addEventListeners to inputs for auto completion.. or something.. that's the concept anyway..